# Is a randomly-generated book a violation of copyright?

Tags: copyright

Let's say I create a computer program that randomly chooses words and records them. Now, this generator spits out an exact word-for-word copy of a non-public-domain book.

If I publish this (without knowing it's a copy), would I be in violation of the original book's copyrights? What if I could reasonably prove that it was generated randomly?

Comment: Similar: [At what point can a computer-generated file infringe copyright?](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1916/529)

Comment: Assume the book is fifty thousand words, drawn from a vocabulary of ten thousand words (and these are fairly low numbers).  The chance of random duplication is 1 in a number expressed by a 1 with two hundred thousand zeros after it.  I'm far more likely to find the winning lottery tickets on the sidewalk for every lottery for the rest of my life.  In other words, this simply isn't going to happen, and any duplication will have been deliberate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copyright infringement requires that you actually **copy** elements from an earlier work produced by a different author. If you created a similar, or even identical, work independently, it is not copyright infringement.

When considering whether or not infringement has occurred, the court is likely to consider whether the defendant could reasonably have had access to the plaintiff's work. If the court finds that they could have, then the defendant would be required to produce evidence of original authorship.

Consider the *My Sweet Lord/He So Fine* case, where the court found the defendant had subconsciously copied the plaintiff's song. Had Harrison been able to produce evidence of original authorship, the judgment could have been different.

In your example, it is unlikely that an suit in copyright infringement could be decided against you, as you've stated the text is generated randomly. However, more evidence of this randomness might be required to support your case.

Of course, whether a computer or automated process can produce works independently is still questionable; I'm not aware of cases that have tried this. The US Copyright Office has said that *Works produced by mechanical processes or random selection without any contribution by a human author are not registrable.* Of course, whether this has a bearing on your particular scenario is undecided, and I'm not sure how it would be decided.

It is almost certain that the worst case outcome would be an injunction requiring you to cease publicising the product, or perform reasonable checks prior to publication to ensure that the product of your program infringes on works; it would be unlikely that you would have costs ordered against you, especially if the program is truly random, and the random text was given as much, or more, publicity than the coherent text.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, because the end result of its application would produce absurd results.  If two works are the same, then one is infringing...very likely the later one.  The meat of the question really is, who would have to pay whom, and how much.  That's where I DO agree with jimsug.

Comment: But that's the point I guess.....the trier of fact would have to believe you because if it was truly random, the likelihood of recreating the results would be like hitting lotto twice in a month. But sure, if you could show to a certainty it was random, I guess you could prevail... Again it comes down to perception and whether the evidence is believable and if it is, by a preponderance of the evidence, shown to be more likely than an infringement.

Comment: It's also worth noting that generating a large number of random books, then sifting through them to find the one that happened to generate a title starting with "Harry Potter and the..." might well be considered "copying". You would have to commit to publishing whatever got spit out, or publish it with no idea that it was similar--a much less likely fact pattern.

Answer (score 4):

You can introduce it, but they would introduce experts who would say the odds are billions-to-one of generating an identical work is possible. In that case, the jury would probably find that it was more likely copied, than independently, yet identically, created.  This would be on the magnitude of a matching but unrelated DNA....wth a 99.95% probability of this being impossible. There are no absolutes in a trial, so *could* you prevail....sure. But my money would be on the plaintiff!

Comment: Even if the defendant produces the other 99.95% of the output that was incomprehensible garbage? I mean, this is probably something unlikely to be tested in court, but... it's hard to imagine that you could be found to be infringing if you could demonstrate true randomness.

Comment: The  OP's question is  still salient if you imagine that 3 pages of a book had been identically recreated, instead of the "silly" and improbable entire book.  That much smaller amount of similarity would be adequate to bring an infringement action.

Answer (score 0):

you would most certainly be in complete violation of the previous book copyright.  The owner of that copyright would have no problem winning a judgement.

However, if you were able to prove that the random text generator had produced the book, you'd likely avoid damages, and merely have to remove your infringing "book" from circulation.

Your example is of course a "silly" one, but it could apply also to the far-less-silly situation where a substantial excerpt...a paragraph or so...matches up.

Comment: Can you provide any support for you first assertion?  [Given](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/a/200/10) that it directly contradicts [the other answer, and the other answerer](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/1989/10) has both legal training and an established reputation of providing correct answers, your answer faces a higher level of scrutiny.

Comment: @feetwet-- here's a reference: http://copyright.gov/history/studies/study25.pdf  The term of interest is "innocent infringement."   from "http://www.law.uci.edu/faculty/full-time/reese/reese_innocent_infringement.pdf": 

The 1976 Act continued the 1909 Act’s approach. Any unexcused violation of
the copyright owner’s exclusive rights was a civil infringement, regardless of the
mental state with which the act was committed, but in some circumstances the
remedies available against an innocent infringer were limited.

Comment: @dwoz AFAIK, innocent infringement does not mean independent recreation. It means actual copying by someone who didn't intend to infringe. For instance, it would cover someone who bought a license from a third party they reasonably thought had the copyright. This isn't a mental-state analysis; independent creation simply isn't an unauthorized violation of the exclusive rights.

Comment: This answer is the correct in that all that is needed to prevail is a legal copyright, access by defendant to the work, along with the work being unique  enough such that it's "more likely than not" that it couldn't be produced without "copying", and the defendant had access to it ( it has been released to the public more than personal access ) than the plaintiff will prevail.  In a civil action,  a preponderance standard is used, whereby you need only show that it's ever so  slightly more likely it was plagiarized  than not. A mere tipping of the scales, 51% odds of infringement, P prevails

Comment: @gracey Even if the defendant can prove the random generation? I agree it's unlikely to be accepted without some serious evidence, but is it actually impossible to introduce evidence of independent creation?

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that a jury would believe an identical copy to a unique work could be randomly generated. Even if you could show that it was theoretically possible, the facts is that under a preponderance standard, most any jury will find it is more likely than not, it was not random. The only way you could win is if the jury thought that was more likely than actually having plagiarized  it. Remember, it is not reality but the perception of reality that becomes "truth

Comment: The point is that there are two tests and two hurdles.  The first is the simple fact or lack thereof of overwhelming similarity.  If that exists, then the subsequent work is infringing.  It doesn't matter how the work came into being or what the second "author" knew or didn't know.  The second test and hurdle is whether the second author is liable for damages or remedies to the original author.   Also, the premise of the question is more palatable if we consider the infringing random-generated work was identical across, say, three pages, instead of the entire book..

Comment: @dwoz that's just not true, though. The fact is, if someone who lived their entire life on an island (and could prove this), with no contact with civilisation or literature but was raised to speak English, produced the entire works of George RR Martin, they wouldn't have infringed copyright. Yes, whether the work came afterward is a strong factor, but whether the author arrived at it independently and/or had access to the plaintiff's work is the key criteria.

Comment: The problem then, @jimsug, is that those two works would be permissible to be sold side-by-side, with no recourse by the initial author? That seems an absurd outcome. This may seem like an academic question, but imagine I recreated a Dr. Seuss children's book, generated by a computer.  We're only talking about perhaps 300 words. I could demonstrate that the source texts for the algorithm did not derive from Seuss.  My illustrations would be different, but the text identical.  I don't think this is an outcome we would see in the real world.  My "work" would be disallowed.

Comment: @dwoz a legal argument based solely on whether something is "fair or absurd" is no legal argument at all. Whether or not something seems absurd of an outcome or not (I need only point you to mandatory minimum sentencing laws as an example) is not a factor in the legal process. And the fact is, this _is_ a legal novelty. We simply _don't_ have any legal precedent to rely on.

Comment: I agree that the whole scenario is absurd. However @jimsug...even your island scenario, how could you prove someone lived on an island with no contact with anyone else? How do you prove the negative assertion? They can say they never had contact, but how do you prove no passerby ever wandered upon the island and left them an iPad to surf the net (lol), or that they never rowed to a neighboring land, or how could they even create the machine to randomize without access to tools and/or parts from outside influences? It would come down to believability and perception of truth at the end.

Comment: I find myself in dismay at the notion that litigators think they can support an identical written work as being non-infringing because of the manner of its generation.  It's nonsense, absurd.  Any judge in the US would toss you on yer ear.  The product is the product.  If a million monkeys typed out "Lord Of The Flies," it's STILL the Lord of The Flies.  The second, subsequent "author" would be enjoined from distributing "his" manuscript.