# Are hash checksums of licensed software copyrighted?

Tags: intellectual-property

I want to distribute a list of MD5 file [checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) of closed source software, in the form:

```
<checksum> <filename>
```

The purpose of this list is to help forensic researchers to identify whether installations have been tampered with.

Am I allowed to do distribute such a list? Or does it depend on the given license?

Generalized, this question is about whether metadata is copyrighted *by the owner of the original IP*. It [was partially asked here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/at-what-point-can-a-computer-generated-file-infringe-copyright/4366#4366) but went unanswered.

Comment: You might want to say what exactly you want to do with this list. I can't see any objections based on copyright, but there may be other objections.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright protection only extends to things requiring a modicum of creativity to construct. A checksum-computing program can be so protected, but the results of running a file through such a program is entirely automatic (well, almost certainly is), and involves no creativity. So the number of not protected.

Comment: Thanks! I understand I can't claim any copyright. But what about the original IP owner, does her copryright extend to meta data such as hash checksums of her files?

Comment: No, since even if the author of the program computed the checksum, there is no creativity involved in doing so. If there were a compression method that reduced a program to a manageable integer from which it could be recreated, that would be a problem: a checksum is not such a thing.

Comment: The checksum/hash or even encrypted code is a direct result of the original work, and not derivative. Since the author presumably created the code, and the resultant executable with checksum and/or hash, why would it not be different than a copy of an encrypted Hollywood movie that was copyrighted?

Comment: Then again, the original work can be reproduced from an encrypted copy but not from a checksum. Perhaps, a unique identification number of a painting would be a better analogy? Especially if the unique identification number is not assigned by the original author but by a third party (me).

Comment: If the thing or a reasonable facsimile can be recreated from a number, the number of a "derivative", which requires permission. A modern equivalent of a Köchel number, or an ISBN, does not embody the work that it refers to.

Comment: If the number requires the copyrighted work, and the copyrighted work require originality, then the number requires originality. Your argument is quite thin.